# Private fields flagged as WithEvents are taken by Code First to build an automatic foreign

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, code-first

a simple question.

Given the following code:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private WithEvents pPerClass As PersistableClass
    Public Overridable Property PerClass() As PersistableClass
        Get
            Return pPerClass
        End Get
        Set(value As PersistableClass)
            pPerClass= value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Other code
    '...

End Class
```

and

```
Public Class PersistableClass
    Public Property PersistableClassID as Integer
    'Other methods and properties
    '...
End Class
```

When MyClass is persisted and the db successfully created using Code First, the following two foreign keys are created in the MyClasses table:

- pPerClass_PersistableClassID (FK,int,null)
- PerClass_PersistableClassID (FK,int,null)

the first being a duplication of the second key, strangely obtained from a private field.

If you remove the WithEvents keyword, the pPerClass_PersistableClassID key is not created.

I am new to EF but it seems to me a strange behaviour.

Do you know any reasons for it?

Comment: I have not used the entity framework but it may have to do with backing fields of delegates being created for events which then get persisted (can also be an issue when serializing objects). See [e.g. this link](http://www.lhotka.net/WeBlog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=776f44e8-aaec-4845-b649-e0d840e6de2c) for a bit more information.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've had a look to the link and it seems to me it make sense. I'll try to figure out what EF actually does during database creation.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason that comes to mind would be a side effect of how `WithEvents` is implemented.  If you open your compiled class in a decompiler, you will see that it has created a property with the name of the WithEvents field and made its own backing field for the property.

Once you've seen it, you can probably understand why this is done if you think about how you would implement the `WithEvents` keyword.  This extra property is used to ensure that the appropriate event handlers are hooked and unhooked when the property is set.

That said, I expect the property would be private and am surprised that it affects EF, though I haven't used EF enough to really know.  This appears to mean that `WithEvents` does not work well with EF, and you need to hook the event handlers manually.

Comment: Thanks Gideon, it could make sense. In the decompiled list of members the newly created property is defined just as any other property and the difference is made by the getter/setter scope declaration. But then when you use reflection it is not available, being private.